# ubuntu 18.04 - removed installed LAMP and on reinstall I have errors

Tags: apt, server, apache2, mysql, php

I hope I didn't break my current ubuntu instance, I was trying to avoid that.
I have followed [this official installation](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#2-install-wordpress) for LAMP + wordpress.

After understanding that this particular installation routine does not have what I need, I moved on to remove this installation in order to start over again with a different installation routine so I ran the following command:

`sudo apt remove wordpress php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql`

After noticing that apache2 wasn't removed I went on to run the following commands to make sure I have a fresh start:

```
# This will remove Apache
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
sudo apt remove apache2.*
sudo apt-get autoremove
whereis apache2
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2

# This will remove PHP
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php7.2| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
whereis php
sudo rm -rf /etc/php

# This will remove MYSql
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql\*
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y
rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo reboot
```

#### now after installing apache2 I have the following error:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-13 10:49:18 IDT; 4h 15min ago

Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost apachectl[1722]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost apachectl[1722]: Action 'start' failed.
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost apachectl[1722]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 13 10:49:18 localghost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I'm a new Linux user and I was hoping not to ruin or even clutter my current instance, which appearantly i've managed to do. Can anyone here give me some guidance how to:

- cleanup current mess
- install LAMP according to the best practice (noticed there are more than a few ways)

Many thanks,

Buddy